# Using python and pandas to compute grouped averages

Tags: python, pandas

```
Lat          Lon        Year    Area    Value   group_a group_b  
-31.3484    -60.0629    2019    70  24  a   ia
-26.8443    -64.5456    2020    492 12  a   ia
-27.6536    -62.2072    2017    173 111 b   md
-26.4552    -61.4804    2020    255 76  b   ct
-35.6044    -63.5238    2019    204 12  a   de
-35.6044    -63.5238    2021    124 26  c   ca
```

I have a dataframe like above. I want to find rows which have duplicate values for both `Lat` and `Lon`, and for those rows I want to compute a value in a new column called `newcol`. That value should be the average of the values in the Value column for those rows. In this example, the last 2 rows have duplicate values for Lat and Lon so the `Value` column values will be averaged to get 19

For the other rows, I want to find the average of the `Value` column based on a combination of `group_a` and group_b`values. E.g. for the rows where`group_a == a`and`group_b == ia`, the values will be averaged together.

The final result should look like this:

```
Lat         Lon         Year    Area    Value   group_a group_b newcol  
-31.3484    -60.0629    2019    70  24  a   ia  18  
-26.8443    -64.5456    2020    492 12  a   ia  18
-27.6536    -62.2072    2017    173 111 b   md  111
-26.4552    -61.4804    2020    255 76  b   ct  76
-35.6044    -63.5238    2019    204 12  a   de  19
-35.6044    -63.5238    2021    124 26  c   ca  19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) operations with `transform('mean')`, and then use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to choose which one to apply to each row. Like this:

```
# get list with True for duplicates:
duplicate_bools = df.loc[:, ['Lat','Lon']].duplicated(keep=False)

# get means based on ['Lat','Lon']
duplicate_means = df.groupby(['Lat','Lon'])['Value'].transform('mean')

# same for ['group_a','group_b']
group_means = df.groupby(['group_a','group_b'])['Value'].transform('mean')

# use `np.where` for assignment
df['newcol'] = np.where(duplicate_bools,duplicate_means,group_means)

print(df)

       Lat      Lon  Year  Area  Value group_a group_b  newcol
0 -31.3484 -60.0629  2019    70     24       a      ia    18.0
1 -26.8443 -64.5456  2020   492     12       a      ia    18.0
2 -27.6536 -62.2072  2017   173    111       b      md   111.0
3 -26.4552 -61.4804  2020   255     76       b      ct    76.0
4 -35.6044 -63.5238  2019   204     12       a      de    19.0
5 -35.6044 -63.5238  2021   124     26       c      ca    19.0
```